# No value specified for parameter - Grails

Tags: grails

I'm having an issue when using a find by on a domain class:

The error I'm getting is:
`ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - No value specified for parameter 2`

The domain classes are:

```
class AppDetail {

String name
String url
Boolean active

static hasMany = [authString:AppIdentifier]


static constraints = {
    name(unique:true,blank:false)
    active(nullable:true)
}

class AppIdentifier {

Date added
String authString

static belongsTo = [authString:AppDetail]

static constraints = {

    added()
    authString(blank:false)

}
```

The find by is:

```
def identifier = AppIdentifer.findByAuthString('test')
def appDetails = AppDetail.findByAuthString(identifier)
```

Can anyone provide any insight into the meaning of this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many fields named "authString".  Here's another way to redo the same classes:

```
class AppDetail {

String name
String url
Boolean active

static hasMany = [identifiers:AppIdentifier]


static constraints = {
    name(unique:true,blank:false)
    active(nullable:true)
}

class AppIdentifier {

Date added
String authString

static belongsTo = [appDetail:AppDetail]

static constraints = {

    added()
    authString(blank:false)

}

def identifier = AppIdentifer.findByAuthString('test')
def appDetails = identifier.appDetail
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined authString both as String AND AppDetail:

```
String authString

static belongsTo = [authString:AppDetail]
```

Either remove `String authString` or change it to `AppDetail authString`

BTW From the point of view of GORM the property naming doesn't matter. But if you define a property with `String` in it's name, but of another class, you gonna get maintenance problems in the future.